# Background color make phantom borders appear when resizing window

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm designing a block that shows a car with information, for this problem particularly I've only left the important thing, the default background (image):

[image: Car background]

The problem is with the background color, it changes with the color received in the view -*red* in the example-. Everything works like a charm until I resize the window (using *Toggle device toolbar*) or when I test it in the final device (1920x1080). If you do this change, you'll see phantom borders appear:

[image: Magic borders]

I've tried adding box-shadow property and with some resolutions the result is the same:

```
box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 0px 8px rgb(255, 255, 255);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 0px 8px #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 0px 8px #fff;
box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 0px 8px #fff;**
```

I'm using:

- Google Chrome
- Android, Samsung device that has a 1920x1080 resolution
- If you don't get the borders, just play resizing the window and they'll appear.

```css
.listitem {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 6px 3px 10px 10px;
}

.listitem-block {
  width: 362px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.listitem-body {
  height: 125px;
  padding: 0px 5px 5px 6px;
  width: 290px;
}

.listitem-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 290px;
  height: 120px;
}

.listitem-bg {
  height: 105px;
  background: #777 url('https://i.imgur.com/FsTDxBK.png') no-repeat;
  width: 287px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  /*     box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 0px 8px rgb(255, 255, 255); */
  /*    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 0px 8px #fff;  Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  /*    -moz-box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 0px 8px #fff;  Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  /*    box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 0px 8px #fff; */
}
```

```html
<div class="listitem-block">
  <div class="ibox">
    <div class="ibox-content product-box">
      <a class="href-none">
        <div class="listitem">
          <!-- Body -->
          <div class="listitem-body">
            <div class="listitem-bg" style="background-color: red"></div>
            <div class="listitem-content">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Complete JSFiddle here (Updated 25/6): https://jsfiddle.net/1uod0ptb/19/

Comment: I don't see the issue in your provided JSFiddle. But my guess would be a device scaling issue? the size of the background image might not match exactly with the size of the box due to half pixels when a device screen is scaled. I've seen random borders appear like this myself when zooming in/out of a page.

Comment: Does this make a difference? https://jsfiddle.net/k98x6ytu/ I added the car image in a pseudo element with a 100% width and height. You could also try your same code but set the background size to be 100% as well maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your response @BlueCaret, i'm sorry but it doesn't work neither. If you play with the resize window (enabling Toggle device toolbar in Chrome) borders appear. I don't get what you're trying to explain with background size to be 100%, height and width are the same as the image that is used for background. Thanks!

Comment: With your example this is the result that I mean (playing with resize window value): https://i.imgur.com/b2D3MvH.png @BlueCaret

Comment: Try adding `background-size: 100% 100%;` to your `.listitem-bg` class.

Comment: @BlueCaret same result :( https://jsfiddle.net/ignacioara/k98x6ytu/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My last idea is to use the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-element and a CSS variable…
The `::before` using this variable color, is positionned to let some space around itself:

```css
.listitem {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 6px 3px 10px 10px;
}

.listitem-block {
  width: 362px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.listitem-body {
  position: relative; /* ADDED THIS */
  height: 125px;
  padding: 0px 5px 5px 6px;
  width: 290px;
}

.listitem-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 290px;
  height: 120px;
}

.listitem-bg { /* Modified a little here */
  position: relative;
  height: 105px;
  width: 287px;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.listitem-bg::before { /* Added all this */
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  background-color: var(--bg-color); /* Using CSS var here */
  content: "";
}

.listitem-bg::after { /* Added all this */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/FsTDxBK.png');
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="listitem-block">
  <div class="ibox">
    <div class="ibox-content product-box">
      <a class="href-none">
        <div class="listitem">
          <!-- Body -->
          <div class="listitem-body">
            <div class="listitem-bg" style="--bg-color: red;"></div><!-- Using CSS var here -->
            <div class="listitem-content">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

It just appeared to me that you're using `position: absolute;` without any `position: relative` element.
Even if it doesn't correct your problem, you should use that!

Please tell me what happens if you use that code:

```css
.listitem {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 6px 3px 10px 10px;
}

.listitem-block {
  width: 362px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.listitem-body {
  position: relative; /* ADDED THIS */
  height: 125px;
  padding: 0px 5px 5px 6px;
  width: 290px;
}

.listitem-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 290px;
  height: 120px;
}

.listitem-bg { /* Modified a little here */
  position: absolute;
  height: 105px;
  width: 287px;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/FsTDxBK.png');
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="listitem-block">
  <div class="ibox">
    <div class="ibox-content product-box">
      <a class="href-none">
        <div class="listitem">
          <!-- Body -->
          <div class="listitem-body">
            <div class="listitem-bg" style="background-color: red"></div>
            <div class="listitem-content">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

I tried to slightly oversize the image with `background-size: 101% 101%;`.
I've also added `background-position: center center` and `background-origin: border-box`.
All of these can be used in the sorthand `background`:

```css
.listitem {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 6px 3px 10px 10px;
}

.listitem-block {
  width: 362px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.listitem-body {
  height: 125px;
  padding: 0px 5px 5px 6px;
  width: 290px;
}

.listitem-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 290px;
  height: 120px;
}

.listitem-bg {
  height: 105px;
  background: #777 url('https://i.imgur.com/FsTDxBK.png') center center / 101% 101% no-repeat border-box;
  width: 287px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<div class="listitem-block">
  <div class="ibox">
    <div class="ibox-content product-box">
      <a class="href-none">
        <div class="listitem">
          <!-- Body -->
          <div class="listitem-body">
            <div class="listitem-bg" style="background-color: red"></div>
            <div class="listitem-content">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

I also wanted to try something different and reset some styles.

I only used `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` and the problem seems to have disappeared for me:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.listitem {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 6px 3px 10px 10px;
}

.listitem-block {
  width: 362px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.listitem-body {
  height: 125px;
  padding: 0px 5px 5px 6px;
  width: 290px;
}

.listitem-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 290px;
  height: 120px;
}

.listitem-bg {
  height: 105px;
  background: #777 url('https://i.imgur.com/FsTDxBK.png') no-repeat;
  width: 287px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<div class="listitem-block">
  <div class="ibox">
    <div class="ibox-content product-box">
      <a class="href-none">
        <div class="listitem">
          <!-- Body -->
          <div class="listitem-body">
            <div class="listitem-bg" style="background-color: red"></div>
            <div class="listitem-content">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I hope one of these methods will work for you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tested both solutions and none of them seem to work. The first one doesn't do anything in elements (I assume there's a clean style in the current application) and the second one only makes the image bigger in right and bottom borders, the top and left phantom borders appear... In which device/browser/resolution are you trying it?

Comment: @IgnacioAra I tried on Chrome v67.0.3396.99 (64 bits) on my desktop PC and also on my Android tablet. I've played with both window size and zoom. Anyway, I've added some more background properties in my snippet. I hope it will help.

Comment: Which resolution has your android tablet? As I mentioned in this issue is 1920x1080 and with your changes the result is the same (https://i.imgur.com/uAY8gXB.png), sorry

Comment: @IgnacioAra My tablet must be 1920x1080. But I tried on this snippet, not in your application! Could you test the code in my snippet with a background size of 102% 102%, just to try ?

Comment: Of course, result is close to last one (https://i.imgur.com/lWjPiob.png). I think that we have found a problem with background behavior in browser and I'm thinking about going to a canvas/icon and to give it a color over the background image and forgetting about this option...

Comment: @IgnacioAra I've added a new snippet in first position. And I've got another spare idea if it doesn't work. :)

Comment: I'm sorry but same result https://i.imgur.com/HgoxBg8.png As I mentioned in another comment I tried many many options but borders always appear, let's check that spare -and I hope final- idea ;)

Comment: You made it! Many thanks for your last idea and your help through the problem :D Here's the reward for you

Comment: @IgnacioAra Thanks! I'm glad it works nicely for you as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style, it fixed the issue for me.

```
.listitem-bg {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Also add `position:relative` on `listitem-body`, its not actually required but its a good practice for an absolute element to have a relative parent div.
Also your html had some unclosed tags. Use my html. I have fixed it.

Removed `no-repeat` from background property. Added top and left:0 on `listitem-bg`

```css
.listitem {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 6px 3px 10px 10px;
}

.listitem-block {
  width: 362px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.listitem-body {
  height: 125px;
  padding: 0px 5px 5px 6px;
  width: 290px;
  position: relative;
}

.listitem-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 290px;
  height: 120px;
}

.listitem-bg {
  height: 105px;
  background: #777 url('https://i.imgur.com/FsTDxBK.png');
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  background-size: cover;
  /*     box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 0px 8px rgb(255, 255, 255); */
  /*  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 0px 8px #fff;  Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  /*    -moz-box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 0px 8px #fff;  Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  /*    box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 0px 8px #fff; */
}
```

```html
<div class="listitem-block">
  <div class="ibox">
    <div class="ibox-content product-box">
      <a class="href-none">
        <div class="listitem">
          <!-- Body -->
          <div class="listitem-body">
            <div class="listitem-bg" style="background-color: red"></div>
            <div class="listitem-content">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/1uod0ptb/21/) here

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated the code as you've suggested (https://jsfiddle.net/1uod0ptb/17/) but the result is the same. When you resize the screen magic borders will appear... Image result: https://i.imgur.com/qEMJUv1.png

Comment: I forgot to mention, your html had some issues too. It had some unclosing tags. You had closed the anchor before the div.. Use my html.,. I have corrected it also..

Comment: Thanks but the problem isn't solved yet :( As you can see in this image (https://i.imgur.com/aNq5PJl.png) taken directly from your snippet

Comment: You just need to open Dev Tools (F12) and resize the screen to lower or higher resolutions (in snippet website). My app resolution is 1920x1080. Thanks!

Comment: @IgnacioAra Check my updated answer and fiddle here.  https://jsfiddle.net/1uod0ptb/21/

Comment: Thanks @Nandita I'm sorry but phantom borders still appear with those changes: https://i.imgur.com/19oa0Md.png

Comment: @IgnacioAra Can you tell me why youi have used so many divs? are they actually required? Can i change your html ?

Comment: You can change whatever you want, @Nandita. I've used so many divs because there's plenty of code deleted (angular checks and behaviors) so that the problem is focused. In your last example the problem still appears (https://i.imgur.com/zBeVd5M.png). In addition, you've used an image instead of a background which had absolute position so that I can put a div over it (with vehicle information).

Comment: Check this fiddle one last time. If it works great , Else i will give up on this :(   https://jsfiddle.net/1uod0ptb/24/

Comment: I'm sorry Nandita but it doesn't :( (https://i.imgur.com/3RXmFuQ.png) I tried many options and finally end up asking in SO because of failed results. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Which browser are you facing this issue.. Browser and version ? My bad i didnt ask about it sooner. Did you try updating your browser ?

Comment: Google Chrome, problem appears in device (Samsung Android with latest chrome vestion) and computer (also last version for Chrome), you have all information needed for testing (resolution also) in main question :)

Comment: YEah  but it doesnt mention the browser version. I knew it was chrome from the ins[ector tools. but just wanted to be sure

Comment: My chrome version is 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (32-bit). Also in my dev tools I see a "mobile" text. Cant see the same in yours. Are you sure your chrome is updated. Please check this https://ibb.co/gOsjvT